# Pandas (Python) - Update column of a dataframe from another one with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I had a problem and I found a solution but I feel it's the wrong way to do it.
Maybe, there is a more 'canonical' way to do it.

**Problem**

I have two dataframe that I would like to merge without having extra column and without erasing existing infos. Example :

Existing dataframe (df)

```
   A  A2  B
0  1   4  0
1  2   5  1
```

Dataframe to merge (df2)

```
   A  A2  B
0  1   4  2
1  3   5  2
```

I would like to update `df` with `df2` if columns 'A' and 'A2' corresponds.
The result would be (:

```
   A  A2    B
0  1   4  2.0 <= Update value ONLY
1  2   5  1.0
```

Here is my solution, but I think it's not a really good one.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,4,0],[2,5,1]],columns=['A','A2','B'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,4,2],[3,5,2]],columns=['A','A2','B'])

df = df.merge(df2,on=['A', 'A2'],how='left')
df['B_y'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['B'] = df['B_x']+df['B_y']
df = df.drop(['B_x','B_y'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Does anyone has a better way to do ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it can be done without merge:

```
rows = (df[['A','A2']] == df2[['A','A2']]).all(axis=1)
df.loc[rows,'B'] = df2.loc[rows,'B']
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks ! :)

Comment: Hi! I have two different DFs (DF1 and DF2) and I'm facing the same problem as here. I've tried this solution but am getting the following error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`. Both DFs are different in size but the columns that matter are labeled the same. Why am I getting this error? I did this: `values = (df[[SITE_IP,PORT_NAME]] == dfLags[[SITE_IP,PORT_NAME]]).all(axis=1)`

Comment: In addition to the columns also the rows have lables stored in the index. For example, with `df3 = df.copy(); df3.index = ['G', 'H']`, the comparison `df[['A','A2']] == df3[['A','A2']]`yields the same error. So even having the same shape, prevents from a valid comparison. Maybe some numpy tricks with broadcasting may help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df.ix[df2.loc[(df['A'] == df2['A']) & (df['A2'] ==   
df2['A2']),'B'].index.values,'B'] = \
df2.loc[(df['A'] == df2['A']) & (df['A2'] == df2['A2']),'B']
```

Comment: A little bit longer than Quickbeam2k1's one, but it does the job. Thanks :)