# Pandas (Python) - Update column of a dataframe from another one with conditions and different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I had a problem and I found a solution but I feel it's the wrong way to do it. Maybe, there is a more 'canonical' way to do it.

I already [had an answer for a really similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863665/pandas-python-update-column-of-a-dataframe-from-another-one-with-conditions), but here I have not the same amount of rows in each dataframe. Sorry for the "double-post", but the first one is still valid so I think it's better to make a new one.

**Problem**

I have two dataframe that I would like to merge without having extra column and without erasing existing infos. Example :

Existing dataframe (df)

```
   A  A2  B
0  1   4  0
1  2   5  1
2  2   5  1
```

Dataframe to merge (df2)

```
   A  A2  B
0  1   4  2
1  3   5  2
```

I would like to update `df` with `df2` if columns 'A' and 'A2' corresponds.
The result would be :

```
   A  A2    B
0  1   4  2 <= Update value ONLY
1  2   5  1
2  2   5  1
```

Here is my solution, but I think it's not a really good one.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,4,0],[2,5,1],[2,5,1]],columns=['A','A2','B'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,4,2],[3,5,2]],columns=['A','A2','B'])

df = df.merge(df2,on=['A', 'A2'],how='left')
df['B_y'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['B'] = df['B_x']+df['B_y']
df = df.drop(['B_x','B_y'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

I tried this solution :

```
rows = (df[['A','A2']] == df2[['A','A2']]).all(axis=1)
df.loc[rows,'B'] = df2.loc[rows,'B']
```

But I have this error because of the wrong number of rows :

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Does anyone has a better way to do ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for check where are same rows in both `DataFrames`. Then create `NaN` by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), which is filled by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html). Last cast to `int`:

```
mask = df[['A', 'A2']].isin(df2[['A', 'A2']]).all(1)
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

df.B = df.B.mask(mask).combine_first(df2.B).astype(int)
print (df)
   A  A2  B
0  1   4  2
1  2   5  1
2  2   5  1
```

Comment: Thank you ! Not so easy, but I will analyse/learn/use this :D

Answer (score 1):

With a minor tweak in the way in which the boolean mask gets created, you can get it to work:

```
cols = ['A', 'A2']
# Slice it to match the shape of the other dataframe to compare elementwise
rows = (df[cols].values[:df2.shape[0]] == df2[cols].values).all(1)
df.loc[rows,'B'] = df2.loc[rows,'B']
df
```

[image]