# Fill pandas DF cell with information from different DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-statements

Hi have arrived to this DF. I'm showing here the interesting columns of it. It's bigger both in rows and columns: `DF.shape = (185, 34)`.

[image]

As you can see, the `outSpeed` field is empty for the lag-like ports.

I have computed a different DF with the outSpeed for LAGs...

```
dfLags = df[df['lag_id'] > 0 ]
dfLags = dfLags.groupby([SITE_IP,'lag_id'])['outSpeed'].sum().reset_index()
dfLags['lag_id'] = 'Lag ' + dfLags['lag_id'].astype(str).str[:-2]
dfLags.rename(columns   = {'lag_id':PORT_NAME}  , inplace = True)
```

... which produces the following ...

```
        Site ID     Port     outSpeed
0     10.2.20.5  Lag 112  10000000000
1     10.2.20.5  Lag 122  10000000000
2     10.2.21.3    Lag 1   2000000000
3     10.2.21.3    Lag 3  20000000000
4     10.2.21.3   Lag 10  20000000000
5   10.2.22.123    Lag 2   3000000000
6   10.2.22.123    Lag 3   2000000000
7   10.2.22.123   Lag 10   6000000000
8    10.2.22.21    Lag 1   3000000000
9    10.2.22.21    Lag 3   2000000000
10   10.2.22.21   Lag 10   6000000000
11   10.2.46.52    Lag 3  20000000000
12   10.2.46.52   Lag 10  20000000000
```

`dfLags.shape = (13, 3)`

So, for example, to complete the original DF, I will have to fill in `Site ID = 10.2.46.52` with `Port = lag 10` the `outSpeed = 20000000000`.

I have not find an easy way of doing so. I mean: how to fill in the original DF's `outSpeed` field conditional to two fields (`site ID,port`), keeping in mind, of course, that the original DF is way bigger?

**EDIT:** I've read this [post], which is the same problem that I'm facing but cannot achieve it yet.

There they suggest doing:

```
values = (dfTemp[[SITE_IP,PORT_NAME]] == dfLags[[SITE_IP,PORT_NAME]]).axis(all=1)
```

... but when running, I get:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

I feel I'm gettin closer. Any ideas?

[post] - [Pandas (Python) - Update column of a dataframe from another one with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863665/pandas-python-update-column-of-a-dataframe-from-another-one-with-conditions)

Comment: Would you mind posting some of your actual data, or is that too much?

Comment: Actually is a rather big file. But found a post with something that looks like a solution, though couldn't make it work yet. I've edited the question.

Comment: What's wrong with `merge()`?

Comment: Hi @andrew_reece. How would you perform the merge, then? I need to fill the `outSpeed` in `DF` with the info from `dfLags`, conditioned to `Site IP` and `Port`, but keeping the rest of `DF` intact ... The problem with merge, as I understand, is that you cannot specify which column to fill (in my case `outSpeed`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` and `add`.

First, some example data:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {"Site ID":["10.2.22.274", "10.2.46.52", "10.2.46.52", "10.2.21.3"],
         "Port":["1/5/7", "Lag 10", "3/2/10", "1/1/7"],
         "outSpeed":[10000000000, None, 10000000000, 3000000000]}

data2 = {"Site ID":["10.2.20.5", "10.2.46.52", "10.2.22.21"],
         "Port":["Lag 112", "Lag 10", "Lag 1"],
         "outSpeed":[10000000000, 20000000000, 3000000000]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1
     Port      Site ID      outSpeed
0   1/5/7  10.2.22.274  1.000000e+10
1  Lag 10   10.2.46.52           NaN
2  3/2/10   10.2.46.52  1.000000e+10
3   1/1/7    10.2.21.3  3.000000e+09

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2
      Port     Site ID     outSpeed
0  Lag 112   10.2.20.5  10000000000
1   Lag 10  10.2.46.52  20000000000
2    Lag 1  10.2.22.21   3000000000
```

In `df1`, `outSpeed` is empty for Site `10.2.46.52`, Port `Lag 10`.  Fill it using the corresponding value from `df2`.
To do that, `merge` on `Site ID` and `Port`, then add the two `outSpeed` columns together into a new `outSpeed`, and drop the unneeded columns:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on=["Site ID", "Port"], how="left")
merged["outSpeed"] = merged.outSpeed_x.add(merged.outSpeed_y, fill_value=0)
merged.drop(["outSpeed_x","outSpeed_y"], 1)

     Port      Site ID      outSpeed
0   1/5/7  10.2.22.274  1.000000e+10
1  Lag 10   10.2.46.52  2.000000e+10
2  3/2/10   10.2.46.52  1.000000e+10
3   1/1/7    10.2.21.3  3.000000e+09
```

Comment: Hi! Sounds interesting. Indeed, this is what I need to achieve finally. But I get an error.... :-( .... : `.assign(outSpeed = merged.outSpeed_x.add(merged.outSpeed_y, fill_value=0))
NameError: name 'merged' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush and trying to compress things.  See updates.

Comment: Hi! Yes, this definitively works! And I understand your reasoning. It's weird how confusing is to extract data from the `dfLags`. I was thinking more on the Excel `VLOOKUP` way: this is something different.  Final words: it is not dropping the columns `outSpeed_x` and `outSpeed_y`. Don't know why ... but I can live with that ... :-) ... thank you very much!

Comment: Great, you're welcome. Try adding `inplace=True` to `drop()` if you want the change to stick.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.loc[(df1["Port"]==df2["Port"]) & (df1["outSpeed"].empty), "outSpeed"] = df2.loc[(df1["Port"]==df2["Port"]) & (df1["outSpeed"].empty), "outSpeed"]
```

Please modify according to your used names

Comment: Hi! Tried your suggestion but it gives me an error: `ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare`. On the other hand: the  `df.loc` needs both rows and columns. In your example, you're matching based on `Port` only and I need both `Site IP` and `Port` to match ... that's the combination where I need to fill the empty `outSpeed` ...

Comment: Above solutions from andrew works. So skip this here.