# How to compare two Dataframe and update a particular column in one of the Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Update: I am having some issue with the answers and guessing it's something to do with the rows are not matching. (updated the today_df so that today and yesterday has diff # of rows).

I need to compare yesterday's dataframe and today's new dataframe to update one column on today's dataframe. for example: 
yesterday_df:

```
fruit      price  qty   comment
apple       1.5   10    In Stock
banana      0.7   20    In Stock
Pear        3.0   5     In Stock
Watermelon  1.2   30    Out Stock
```

today_df  (updated the today_df so that today and yesterday has diff # of rows)

```
fruit      price  qty   comment
apple       1.5   10    
Strawberry  1.7   20    
Pineapple   0.9   5     
Watermelon  1.2   30   
Peach       2.1   10
```

Desired output:
today_df

```
fruit      price  qty   comment
apple       1.5   10    In Stock  <-- from yesterday
Strawberry  1.7   20               <-- empty
Pineapple   0.9   5                 <-- empty
Watermelon  1.2   30    Out Stock   <-- From Yesterday
peach       2.1   10                <-- empty
```

For Today's Dataframe, the comment from previous day for Apple and Watermelon were carried over and the new info (Strawberry and Pineapple) from data were left blank.

i've tried to use series mapping:

```
fruit_map = yesterday_df.set_index('fruit')['Comment']
today_df['Comment']=today_df['fruit'].map(fruit_map).fillna(today_df['Comment'])
today_df
```

but getting this error:

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index
>   objects

```
fruit_map = yesterday_df.set_index('fruit')['Comment']
today_df['Comment']=today_df['fruit'].map(fruit_map).fillna(today_df['Comment'])
today_df

today_df
fruit      price  qty   comment
apple       1.5   10    In Stock
Strawberry  1.7   20    
Pineapple   0.9   5     
Watermelon  1.2   30    Out Stock
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas (Python) - Update column of a dataframe from another one with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863665/pandas-python-update-column-of-a-dataframe-from-another-one-with-conditions)

Comment: What should happen if the price and quantity for a fruit are different from today to yesterday?

Comment: @William .Wu: check your `fruit` column of `yesterday_df`. It must have some duplicate values (same fruit names). I mean in your real data, not the sample you posted above. Run `yesterday_df.fruit.duplicated()` to see any `True`

Comment: Andy, you are right, that was the issue... in the real data, there's duplicates in the index "fruit" Thanks for your help.

Comment: @William.Wu:  glad I could help. See my edited post if you don't want to get rid of duplicates in 'yesterday_df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right path, but you can leverage indexes to assign values so there's no need for map. When you assign values to a dataframe using a Series, it'll align on the index. The key here is to make sure that you're using "fruit" as the index for both dataframes. The easiest way to do this is:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

yesterday = """
fruit,price,qty,comment,col to show it works with different shapes
apple,1.5,10,In Stock,bleh
banana,0.7,20,In Stock,blah
Pear,3.0,5,In Stock,bip
Watermelon,1.2,30,Out Stock,bop
"""

today = """
fruit,price,qty,comment
apple,1.5,10,
Strawberry,1.7,20,
Pineapple,0.9,5,
Watermelon,1.2,30,
Peach,2.1,10,
"""

yesterday_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(yesterday), sep=",").set_index("fruit")
today_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(today), sep=",").set_index("fruit")

today_df["comment"] = yesterday_df["comment"]

today_df

Out[1]: 
            price  qty    comment
fruit                            
apple         1.5   10   In Stock
Strawberry    1.7   20        NaN
Pineapple     0.9    5        NaN
Watermelon    1.2   30  Out Stock
Peach         2.1   10        NaN
```

Alternatively, you could set the index to 'fruit' when you read in your data and avoid the `set_index` call.

You might also want to clean up you index ('fruit' column) by lower casing it since string indexes are case sensitive. For example, if yesterday you had "Apple" and today it was  "apple", this wouldn't work.

Also, I'm assuming you're not interested in changing anything about 'price' or 'qty'.

Comment: It seems to me that it only worked when today_df (4,4) and y_df (4,4) have same shape. if they are different, then, it's not working... is it the reason, or I am getting some other thing wrong?

Comment: @William.Wu The way this works is by assigning the value from yesterday_df["comment"] column to the "comment" column for all rows sharing the same index in today_df, so the key is to make sure that your index is the "fruit" column. You can read more about it here: https://medium.com/dunder-data/selecting-subsets-of-data-in-pandas-part-3-d5704b4b9116

edit: I updated the example to show it works with different shapes

Comment: Thanks, it worked; my data has some duplicates in index, i.e. "fruits".

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Since your `yesterday_df` has some duplicates in `fruit`, you commands throw the errors you posted. Any solution using `index` also errors out. You have 2 ways to solve it.

Method 1: get rid duplicates in `yesterday_df` and your solution using `map` as you posted would work without any issue.

Method 2: Change your solution a little bit with groupby `yesterday_df` on `fruit` and pick `first` of each group to use for updating `today_df` as follows:

```
fruit_map = y_df.groupby('fruit').first()['comment']
t_df['comment'] = t_df['fruit'].map(fruit_map).fillna(t_df['comment'])
```

---

**Original:**
with data as belows:

```
y_df

Out[2896]:
        fruit  price  qty    comment
0       apple    1.5   10   In Stock
1      banana    0.7   20   In Stock
2        Pear    3.0    5   In Stock
3  Watermelon    1.2   30  Out Stock

t_df
Out[2897]:
        fruit  price  qty comment
0       apple    1.5   10
1  Strawberry    1.7   20
2   Pineapple    0.9    5
3  Watermelon    1.2   30
```

---

You just need this command

```
t_df.comment = y_df.comment.where((y_df.price == t_df.price) & (y_df.fruit == t_df.fruit), '')

Out[2908]:
        fruit  price  qty    comment
0       apple    1.5   10   In Stock
1  Strawberry    1.7   20
2   Pineapple    0.9    5
3  Watermelon    1.2   30  Out Stock
```

Comment: got this error message: 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects' 
what could be the cause?  I have checked that both y_df and t_df has same structure and same column name (comment, price, etc.) 
Note: the number of rows might be different, i.e. y_df may have 4 rows and t_df may have more or less rows (2 rows or 5 rows) does that matter?

Comment: @William.Wu: The original solution only works on same dimension `df`. please see my edit for updated solutions.